# Replace a word in a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace tmb with det in this string:

http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/69/11176945_tmb.jpg

This my code I tried.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var $apikey = 'myapikey',
            $apiURL = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0.json?apikey=',
            $topboxoffice = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/upcoming.json?apikey=',
            $topboxofficeSearch = $topboxoffice + $apikey;

        $.ajax({
            url: $topboxofficeSearch,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(response){


                var $movies = response.movies,
                    $moviehtml = $("#movies");


                $.each($movies, function(index, $movie){
                    var $poster = $movie.posters.original;

                    $poster.replace("tmb", "det");

                    //console.log($poster);

                    $("#movies").append( '<img src= '+$poster+ '>');
                });
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I tried to use javascript .replace() but that didn't seem to work. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign te replacement. Te `replace()` function returns the replacement result

```
$poster = $poster.replace("tmb", "det");
```

Comment: Cool Thanks man. I appreciate this! I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes.